# Docker: Opening the tcp socket failed

Tags: docker, tcp, mqtt, alpine-linux, opc-ua

I have a docker image(base image: alpine) in raspberry pi in which there is a program to convert OPCUA messages to MQTT by connecting it to OPCUA server and MQTT broker.

Both the OPCUA server and MQTT broker are on a same Ubuntu vm.

When I try to connect it with their IP instead of dns it is getting connected. But when I try to connect it with it's hostname it throws an error that-->
Opening of tcp socket failed. Couldn't connect the client to a TCP secure channel.

Note: on raspberry pi os is Raspbian.

Comment: Edit the question to explain the layout some more. e.g. is the VM hosted on the same machine as the docker container? Secondly how are the hostnames resolved? mDNS or with a real DNS entry?

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope it will clear all questions.

Comment: You haven't answered the question about how the hostnames are resolved.